# Where is the documentation for Fragment.onCreateAnimator()?

Tags: android, documentation

The entire documentation for the [`Fragment.onCreateAnimator(int, boolean, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimator%28int,%20boolean,%20int%29) method consists of the following text:

> "Called when a fragment loads an animation."

That's it. No explanation about the parameters.

What do the parameters mean? [Even the source code doesn't reveal much.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L1175)

Comment: Seems this results of the method usage could give an idea http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.2.2_r1@android%24app@Fragment@onCreateAnimator%28int%2Cboolean%2Cint%29&k=u

Answer (score 16):

The `onCreateAnimator` method is odd.
The prototype I've seen is this:

`public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)`

`int transit` - transition type, as sandrstar said above

`boolean enter` - true if 'entering,' false otherwise

`int nextAnim` - **The resource ID of the animation that is about to play.**

So, for example, if you tried doing a card flip, [from the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html):

```
// Create and commit a new fragment transaction that adds the fragment for the back of
// the card, uses custom animations, and is part of the fragment manager's back stack.
BackOfCardFragment backFragment = new BackOfCardFragment();

getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()

    // Replace the default fragment animations with animator resources representing
    // rotations when switching to the back of the card, as well as animator
    // resources representing rotations when flipping back to the front (e.g. when
    // the system Back button is pressed).
    .setCustomAnimations(
         R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
         R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

    // Replace any fragments currently in the container view with a fragment
    // representing the next page (indicated by the just-incremented currentPage
    // variable).
    .replace(R.id.container_view, backFragment)

    // Add this transaction to the back stack, allowing users to press Back
    // to get to the front of the card.
    .addToBackStack(null)

    // Commit the transaction.
    .commit();
```

**NOTE: R.id.container_view in the above example is the ID of a ViewGroup that contains the existing fragment you are trying to replace.**

When the above code is executed, the `onCreateAnimator` method will get called, and the `nextAnim` parameter will be one of the four animation IDs passed into the `setCustomAnimations()` function, i.e. R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out... etc.

This doesn't seem immediately useful at first, since it doesn't give you a reference to the actual Animator object that you could attach a listener to. But oddly, you can just inflate another Animator directly from the `nextAnim` resource, and then attach listeners to that, which will, oddly, fire all the overridden callbacks at the right times:

```
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    Animator animator = null;
    // In this example, i want to add a listener when the card_flip_right_in animation
    // is about to happen.
    if (nextAnim == R.animator.card_flip_right_in) {
        animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), nextAnim);
        // * Sometimes onCreateAnimator will be called and nextAnim will be 0, 
        //   causing animator to be null.
        // * I wanted to add a listener when the fragment was entering - 
        //   your use case may be different.
        if (animator != null && enter) {

            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                   // Do something when the card flip animation begins
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                   // Do something as soon as the card flip animation is over
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return animator;
}
```

In this way, you should be able to add listeners to the fragment transition animators as if you had created them yourself.

Comment: I use setCustomAnimations in a fragment and override OnAnimationCreate method of the fragment. Always transit and nextAnim are zero even after using of setTransition method!

Answer (score 6):

Based on [FragmentManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#731) code and usages of [FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimator(android.app.Fragment,int,boolean,int)](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.2.2_r1@android%24app@FragmentManagerImpl@loadAnimator%28android.app.Fragment,int,boolean,int%29&k=u) it seems that [Fragment.onCreateAnimator(int, boolean, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimator%28int,%20boolean,%20int%29) lets You define own animations for fragment hiding, showing, changing state. However, I've never seen usage of it in real apps.

Regarding parameters:

- `int transit` - transition type (constants [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html), e.g. used in [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.transitToStyleIndex%28int,boolean%29));
- `boolean enter` - `true` if it's state enter, false - otherwise;
- `int transitionStyle` - id of style from resources (that style might contain animations missed from `onCreateAnimator`);

Comment: Thanks for digging into this further. I put a `Log.d()` statement at the beginning of the `onCreateAnimator()` method and discovered that `transit` is always set to `0` when swapping fragments.

Comment: @NathanOsman are you calling setTransit() on your fragment transaction?

Comment: @JakeCataford I use customAnimation in a fragment and override OnAnimationCreate method of the fragment. Always transit and nextAnim are zero even after using of setTransition method!