# Android objectAnimator animations are REALLY slow

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, genymotion, objectanimator

At first, I thought my animations just weren't working at all, because the new Fragment ViewGroup would just appear on screen in one frame. Then I slowed the animation down so it would take 3 secs (3000 milliseconds) and discovered that it's just happening in such large chunks that it all happened in one frame. When I increased it to 3 secs, it was getting about 4 frames per second, which is pretty bad. I'm running with a Genymotion Emulator. The Emulator seems very fast in general, when I'm clicking through the Settings app, for example.

I'm just starting development on this app, so it's not doing anything. It's mostly just a shell so far and I'm trying to animate a new Fragment onto the screen.

The new ViewGroup is a custom class called SlideableLayout, which provides this property:

```
public float getXFraction() {
    final int width = getWidth();
    if (width != 0) {
        return getX() / getWidth();
    } else {
        return getX();
    }
}

public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
    Log.d("SL", "setting xFraction="+xFraction);
    final int width = getWidth();
    if (width > 0) {
        setX(xFraction * width);
    } else {
        setX(-10000);
    }
}
```

Then I add the Fragment like so:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_from_right, R.animator.slide_out_to_the_left,
            R.animator.slide_in_from_the_left, R.animator.slide_out_to_the_right)
    .add(R.id.navrootlayout, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

The `R.animator.slide_in_from_right` animation looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_cubic"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="xFraction"
        android:duration="@integer/navigation_animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

So, the system should animation the `xFraction` property from `1.0` to `0.0` and each frame should be calculated VERY quickly since all it does is get the `width` and multiply by the fraction.

I'm not sure why it's running at such a low frame rate. I've tried it on a physical device and it was fine.

EDIT:

Are there some kinds of configuration options that I need to set on my Genymotion emulator in order to make the animations go at a normal frame rate?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is duration set as?

Comment: 3000 milliseconds (i.e. 3 seconds)

Comment: Is this using a custom test app to remove your code from animation equation? You want to isolate it to identify if its a code problem or if its an animation problem. By isolating the animation code into a simple test app scenario, you can isolate these conditions.

Comment: There is no other real code in my project, I'm just starting a new app right now. It's just a fragment with a button, then when you tap that button it animates a new fragment into place. That's all the app does at this point. It would be very difficult to strip it down any further.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is caused by xFraction and yFraction, which have to be implemented by both fragments' root views: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25701362/2964379

Honestly, that's just an epic fail. Does Google expect people to extend every single view for that just to add those two methods?

An easy but horrible solution is to set the property to x or y and set the values to a large number equal to or bigger than the screen, then it works fast but depending on the value there might be huge gaps in the animation.

The best solution (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480676/2964379) is to set your animators to x or y, but completely remove `valueFrom` and `valueTo`. Then override all fragments' `onCreateAnimator` (in a custom fragment base class), use `AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(activity, nextAnim)` to get the animator set and call `setFloatValues` on its child. For example, you can check `nextAnim == R.animator.slide_in_from_right` and call `setFloatValues(screenWidth, 0)`. Works great!