# Fragment - Wait until transaction animation is complete

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am using a simple slide left, slide right custom animation when I perform FragmentTransaction.  My problem is, the fragment I'm loading with the transaction animation contains code in the onResume() to make a HTTP call which causes my "Please Wait" progress dialog to show.  It works, but I would like the move my code from onResume to another method in the Fragment that would not fire until the fragment is completely loaded.  In other words, when the animation is complete and it is completely slid into place.

I use this to start the new fragment

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, new MyFragment());
ft.commit();
```

and I want the method in MyNewFragment() to initialize after the animation is 100% complete

Is that possible?

Comment: @Tony - was just about to accept your answer as correct and you deleted it

Comment: The best explanation for fragment animation is available here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480676/1972597). However, I would recommend the second approach from my answer for your particular problem as it would be a better user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches possible here,

1. Implement an AnimationListener on the slide-in animation.

   ```
   animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
               @Override
               public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

               }
           });
   ```

In onAnimationEnd() of the listener, call a method in the fragment to make the HTTP call.

2. The above approach wastes time just for the sake of the animation. So, instead of having a progress dialog, implement a circular progress bar within your fragment. That way your animation and http call can happen simultaneously. Once you get the response, remove the progress spinner and show your actual fragment views.

Comment: I'm using XML based animations, how would I add a animation listener with that?

Comment: @Phil did you find a solution for your problem?